# Plsql cursor active set results are not in order

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I'm investigating an prod issue which has data as below in DB:

```
11
22
33
44
55
```

The cursor brings out the active set result in a random order sometimes as below :

```
44
55
11
22
33
```

Is this possible and valid?

Comment: can you show us a fiddle where this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **only** way to make sure that query will return rows in desired order is to - guess what? - use the `order by` clause.

So:

```
declare
  cursor c1 is
    select value
    from your_table
    order by value;        --> this
```

Anything else is just pure luck (whether you will, or will not, get rows the way you thought you should).